# Is it possible to use a fixed point iteration for solving this nonlinear system?

Tags: nonlinear-equations, discontinuous-galerkin, fixed-point

Consider the following differential equation
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f(u)}{\partial x} &= g(x), \ \ x\in [x_{L},x_{R}] \label{Eq2.2} \\
u(x_{L}) &= g_{1} 
\end{align}
where $f(u)$ is a nonlinear function. Let $\{x_{i}\}_{i=1}^{N+1}$ be a partition of $\Omega$ with $N$ elements such that
\begin{equation}
x_{L} = x_{1}<x_{2}<\cdots<x_{N}<x_{N+1} = x_{R}
\end{equation}
where $D_{k} = [x_{k},x_{k+1}]$. The weak formulation of the problem is
\begin{equation}
\int_{D_{k}} \Bigg[ -f(u)\frac{d \phi_{i}^{k}}{d x}\Bigg] = \int_{D_{k}} g(x)\phi_{i}^{k}-\Big[(f(u))^{*}\phi_{i}^{k}  \Big]_{x_{k}}^{x_{k+1}}  \label{WeakFormulationNL}
\end{equation}
where the numerical flux $(f(u))^{*}$ is given by
\begin{equation}
(f(u))^{*} = \{f(u)\}+\frac{C}{2}[\hspace{-0.6mm}[ u ]\hspace{-0.6mm}]
\end{equation}
where $\{\cdot\}$ is the average, $[\hspace{-0.6mm}[ \cdot ]\hspace{-0.66mm}]$ is the jump and $C$ is given by $C = \max{ |f(u)| }$. After the space discretization we get a system of the form
\begin{equation}
-r(u_{h}) = b-w(u_{h})
\end{equation}
which can be rewritten as follows
\begin{equation}
r(u_{h}) + b-w(u_{h}) = 0
\end{equation}
The entries of the operators $r(u_{h})$ and $b_{k}$ in the element $D_{k}$ are given by
\begin{align}
(r_{k})_{i} &= \int_{D_{k}} f(u)\frac{d \phi_{i}^{k}}{d x} \\
(b_{k})_{i} =& \int_{D_{k}} g(x,t)\phi_{i}^{k}
\end{align}
where $w(u_{h})$ in the element $D_{k}$ is the term $\Big[(f(u))^{*}\phi_{i}^{k}  \Big]_{x_{k}}^{x_{k+1}}$.
Let $F(u_{h}):= r(u_{h}) + b-w(u_{h})$, then we have a nonlinear system of the form $F(u_{h}) = 0$. I want to rewrite this in the form $G(u_{h}) = u_{h}$ in order to solve the system using a fixed point iteration.

Here's my attempt: let $\lambda \neq 0$ then
\begin{align*}
F(u_{h}) =& 0 \implies \\
r(u_{h}) + b-w(u_{h}) =& 0  \implies \\
r(u_{h}) + b-w(u_{h})+\lambda u_{h}  =& \lambda u_{h} \implies \\
\frac{1}{\lambda}\Big[r(u_{h}) + b-w(u_{h})+\lambda u_{h} \Big]=&  u_{h}
\end{align*}
Then we define
\begin{equation}
G(u_{h}) = \frac{1}{\lambda}\Big[r(u_{h}) + b-w(u_{h})+\lambda u_{h} \Big]
\end{equation}
**My first question is:**
Do you think is possible to use the fixed point iteration to solve the nonlinear system?
if it is possible:
Do you think this approach is correct? or Do you know a better way to solve the system? (Without Newton's method)

Comment: So by simple integration $f(u(x))=f(u(x_L))+\int_{x_L}^xg(s)\,ds$? The second boundary condition is then in general not possible to meet. // Please define all your symbols, like $\{f(u)\}$ or $[[u]]$.

Comment: $\{\cdot\}$ is the average and $[[ \cdot ]]$ is the jump.

Comment: For this one-dimensional advection equation, you can only pose boundary conditions on one side (typically the left side).

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Thank you professor.   I'm not sure if a fixed point iteration is suitable for solving this nonlinear system.  According to your experience, is it possible to solve the system using a fixed point iteration?

Comment: I don't see the benefit. A fixed point iteration is only useful if the equation you have to solve in each step is easier to solve than the original one. But yours is still nonlinear. How are you going to solve it?

Comment: I already solve the system using Newton's method,  but I want to have a different option to solve the system. The reason for this, is that the jacobian of $F(u_{h})$ is computational expensive to compute.   Do you know an alternative to solve the system?

Comment: This might be of help. https://wiki.math.ntnu.no/_media/ma2501/2014v/fixedpoint.pdf